# make command gives error during installation of SURFEX code

Tags: software-installation, make

I need to install and compile SURFEX code on Ubuntu 18.04. To do that I'm following the docs [here](https://www.umr-cnrm.fr/surfex/spip.php?article191). This went well until I tried to compile the master version of the code with `make`. I got Error 127. I looked up the meaning of this error, but I don't really understand what it means in this context. Any help greatly appreciated.

The full message is as follows

```
[ ! -d /home/sarah/MYDIR/open_surfex_v8_1_20210914/open_SURFEX_V8_1/src/LIB/eccodes-2.18.0-LXgfortran-build ] && mkdir -p /home/sarah/MYDIR/open_surfex_v8_1_20210914/open_SURFEX_V8_1/src/LIB/eccodes-2.18.0-LXgfortran-build
Makefile:422: recipe for target '/home/sarah/MYDIR/open_surfex_v8_1_20210914/open_SURFEX_V8_1/src/LIB/eccodes-2.18.0-Source-LXgfortran/include/grib_api.mod' failed
make: [/home/sarah/MYDIR/open_surfex_v8_1_20210914/open_SURFEX_V8_1/src/LIB/eccodes-2.18.0-Source-LXgfortran/include/grib_api.mod] Error 1 (ignored)
cd /home/sarah/MYDIR/open_surfex_v8_1_20210914/open_SURFEX_V8_1/src/LIB/eccodes-2.18.0-LXgfortran-build && \
cmake /home/sarah/MYDIR/open_surfex_v8_1_20210914/open_SURFEX_V8_1/src/LIB/eccodes-2.18.0-Source -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/sarah/MYDIR/open_surfex_v8_1_20210914/open_SURFEX_V8_1/src/LIB/eccodes-2.18.0-Source-LXgfortran -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON \
-DENABLE_NETCDF=OFF -DENABLE_JPG=OFF -DENABLE_PYTHON=OFF -DENABLE_EXAMPLES=OFF \
-DCMAKE_Fortran_COMPILER=f77 -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=mpicc \
-DCMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS= -DCMAKE_C_FLAGS= && \
make && make install && make clean
/bin/sh: 2: cmake: not found
Makefile:422: recipe for target '/home/sarah/MYDIR/open_surfex_v8_1_20210914/open_SURFEX_V8_1/src/LIB/eccodes-2.18.0-Source-LXgfortran/include/grib_api.mod' failed
make: *** [/home/sarah/MYDIR/open_surfex_v8_1_20210914/open_SURFEX_V8_1/src/LIB/eccodes-2.18.0-Source-LXgfortran/include/grib_api.mod] Error 127
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to compilation log

> ```
> /bin/sh: 2: cmake: not found
> ```

you have to install [the package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?mode=exactfilename&suite=bionic&section=all&arch=any&keywords=bin%2Fcmake&searchon=contents) which provides `cmake` executable by

```
sudo apt-get install cmake
```

---

The reproducible method of SURFEX installation for Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS is below:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential cmake libopenmpi-dev gfortran git libcurl4-openssl-dev libnetcdf-dev

cd ~/Downloads
wget -c https://www.umr-cnrm.fr/surfex/data/OPEN-SURFEX/open_surfex_v8_1_20210914.tar.gz
tar -xf open_surfex_v8_1_20210914.tar.gz
cd open_SURFEX_V8_1/src
./configure
. ../conf/profile_surfex-LXgfortran-SFX-V8-1-1-MPIAUTO-OMP-O2-X0
make
sudo make installmaster
```