# configure: error: Could not link to netcdf C library (SURFEX installation fail)

Tags: software-installation, configuration, fortran

I want to install and run SURFEX on Ubuntu 18.04, so I'm following the steps explained [here](https://www.umr-cnrm.fr/surfex/spip.php?article191). when I run the `make` command in the src directory (compiling the master version of the code), after a while I get an error that says:

```
configure: error: Could not link to netcdf C library. Please set LDFLAGS; for static builds set LIBS to the results of nc-config --libs.
```

I tried [this](https://www.unidata.ucar.edu/support/help/MailArchives/netcdf/msg14856.html) solution in the step before "make", i.e.

```
CFLAGS=$(nc-config --cflags) LDFLAGS=$(nc-config --libs) ./configure
```

and

```
CFLAGS=$(nc-config --cflags) LDFLAGS=$(nc-config --libs) . ../conf/profile_surfex-LXgfortran-SFX-V8-1-1-MPIAUTO-O2-X0
```

but I couldn't resolve the problem, probably because I don't know what I am doing. Could someone tell me how I set those flags?

Comment: Is the netcdf development package installed on your system? Did the `nc-config` commands execute without error?

Comment: Have you followed https://askubuntu.com/a/1374166/66509 ?

Comment: @N0rbert, yes and that works, until I get this new error. I tried to solve it myself first and then I was busy for a while, so I'm picking it back up now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I faced the same problem with Ubuntu 20.04 and this solution of theWrongAlice did the trick for me as well.

Installing libcurl4-gnutls-dev:

sudo apt-get install -y libcurl4-gnutls-dev

And before make:

CFLAGS=$(nc-config --cflags) LDFLAGS=$(nc-config --libs) ./configure

Answer (score 0):

Apparently one package isn't listed on the site with instructions. You also need to install libcurl4-gnutls-dev. It works now.